# Pull requests from forks does not trigger travis ci

Tags: github, travis-ci

We seem to have an issue merging pull requests which are from forks like [here](https://github.com/OpenSimulationInterface/open-simulation-interface/pull/385#partial-pull-merging) and [here](https://github.com/OpenSimulationInterface/open-simulation-interface/pull/386). Creating pull request from branches is totally fine and is being triggered by travis ci. Is there some settings which needs to be set for the travis CI? See the travis file [here](https://github.com/OpenSimulationInterface/open-simulation-interface/blob/master/.travis.yml). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from [travis team](https://travis-ci.community/t/pull-requests-from-forks-does-not-trigger-travis-ci/8393):

The checks on the links are branch builds. For them to work, the PR author needs to set up Travis integration for their repo, too, with [travis-ci.com](https://travis-ci.com/), and run a build for the tip of the PR branch. It is this build that the PR UI is “waiting for the status to be reported” of.

The check that would run in your repo is the PR build. It runs on a “merge preview” commit that Github autogenerates for PRs.

The types of the checks to run you configure in branch protection settings at Github.